# COMO PUEDO CONVERTIR UN EXCEL A BASE64 EN PHP CON LA LIBRERIA "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet"

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpspreadsheet

Como puedo capturar el archivo excel y codificarlo a base64 en esta libreria PhpSpreadSheet, en este ejemplo solo lo puedo guardar y hacer que se descargue automaticamente pero necesito capturarlo en base64

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
 
$documento = new Spreadsheet();
$documento
    ->getProperties()
    ->setCreator("Aquí va el creador, como cadena")
    ->setLastModifiedBy('Parzibyte') // última vez modificado por
    ->setTitle('Mi primer documento creado con PhpSpreadSheet')
    ->setSubject('El asunto')
    ->setDescription('midocumento')
    ->setKeywords('etiquetas o palabras clave separadas por espacios')
    ->setCategory('La categoría');
 
$hoja = $documento->getActiveSheet();
$hoja->setTitle("El título de la hoja");
$hoja->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, 1, "Un valor en 1, 1");
$hoja->setCellValue("B2", "Este va en B2");
$hoja->setCellValue("A3", "Parzibyte");
 
$writer = new Xlsx($documento);
 
# Aqui lo descargamos
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="REPORTE_DE_VENTA.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$writer->save('php://output');
```

Answer (score 0):

No envíes encabezados y captura la salida en un búfer.

- [ob_start()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.ob-start.php) inicializa el búfer de salida, capturando todo el contenido
- [ob_get_clean()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.ob-get-clean.php) obtiene el contenido de la salida y finaliza el búfer.

Solo es necesario agregar unas cuantas líneas:

```
ob_start();
$writer->save('php://output');
$contenido = ob_get_clean();

// Ya puedes codificar sin problema
$base64 = base64_encode($contenido);
```

Comment: ya tengo la base64 y ahora como puedo hacer para decodificarlo y que se descargue el archivo excel, lo estoy manejando en una api y estoy enviando la base64 a otra direccion, en el otro servidor tengo que decodificarlo y guardarlo o descargarlo directamente en el navegador

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas convertirlo a base64, mejor indica que es un archivo binario:

```
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
```

Comment: como lo aplicaria segun el ejemplo que coloque arriba

Comment: @Luis Sólo agrégalo a los encabezados que ya tienes, antes de llamar al método `save()`.

Comment: header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="REPORTE_DE_VENTA.xlsx"');
  header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');  
  $writer->save('php://output');

Comment: agregue eso pero aun sigue exportando el excel

Comment: @Luis ¿Exportando?

Answer (score 0):

Para capturar la base64 utilicé este código:

```
        ob_start();
        $writer->save('php://output');
        $contenido = ob_get_clean();
        $base64 = base64_encode($contenido);
        $excel = $base64;
```

Para decodificarlo

```
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="REPORTE_DE_VENTA.xlsx"');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

        // decodificando excel
        echo base64_decode($b64);
        ob_get_contents();
```